# No matter what I specify in settings.py, other template directories not recognized

Tags: python, django

In my settings.py file I've tried a number of different things, but no matter what I put, it never checks beyond `/home/orangeman555/templates/`.

```
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
/home/orangeman555/templates/home.html (File does not exist)
```

Here is what I have for the TEMPLATES setting:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

                # `allauth` specific context processors
                'allauth.account.context_processors.account',
                'allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount',                
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I've tried a variety of things based on stackexchange errors, but no TEMPLATE_DIRS setting seems to get it to "wake up"

This is in a life environment - you can see the errors [here](http://xyzai.com/)

What could I possibly be missing?

```
.
├── db.sqlite3
├── fabfile.py
├── fabfile.py~
├── fabfile.pyc
├── manage.py
├── req.tx
├── static
│   ├── fonts
│   │   └── bootstrap
│   │       ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
│   │       ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
│   │       ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
│   │       ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
│   │       └── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
│   ├── images
│   ├── javascripts
│   │   ├── bootstrap
│   │   │   ├── affix.js
│   │   │   ├── alert.js
│   │   │   ├── button.js
│   │   │   ├── carousel.js
│   │   │   ├── collapse.js
│   │   │   ├── dropdown.js
│   │   │   ├── modal.js
│   │   │   ├── popover.js
│   │   │   ├── scrollspy.js
│   │   │   ├── tab.js
│   │   │   ├── tooltip.js
│   │   │   └── transition.js
│   │   ├── bootstrap.js
│   │   ├── bootstrap.min.js
│   │   └── bootstrap-sprockets.js
│   └── stylesheets
│       ├── framework.css
│       └── styles.css
├── templates # ********TRYING TO LOAD THIS HERE *********
│   ├── base.html
│   ├── flatpages
│   │   └── default.html
│   ├── footer.html
│   ├── home.html
│   ├── menu.html
│   ├── payment-cancel.html
│   ├── payment.html
│   ├── payment-return.html
│   └── profile.html
└── vendsite
    ├── db.sqlite3
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.py~
    ├── __init__.pyc
    ├── settings.py
    ├── settings.pyc
    ├── signals.py
    ├── signals.pyc
    ├── urls.py
    ├── urls.pyc
    ├── views.py
    ├── views.pyc
    ├── wsgi.py
    └── wsgi.pyc
```

Comment: Have you checked file and directory permissions and ownership?

Comment: no I didn't do that.

Comment: It seems fine, having checked

Comment: Where are the templates that you are trying to load?

Comment: I've just updated comment. See ***trying to load here*** text -- that is what I cannot seem to reach for the life of me. Every setting I input is unresponsive and I get the same error without any changes in paths and whatnot.

Comment: as a horrible and in-elegant solution I've simply patched it with `ln -s /home/orangeman555/webapps/testsite/vendsite/templates` in my home directory

Comment: what did you set in your `urls.py`?

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again? If the server is completely unresponsive to your changes, it sounds like you didn't restart the server.

Comment: Have you tried using an absolute path in `DIRS`? I.e. `'DIRS': ['/home/orangeman555/templates/']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this setup in my django 1.8:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
ROOT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

PROJECT_HOST = 'servername.com'
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

import os.path
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'static/')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'


from django.conf.global_settings import TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS += (
    "django.core.context_processors.request",

)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
)
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader'
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#   'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
```

end when i have project/templates/base.html -its works fine
and even when i have project/application/templates/app_html.html it works too.
If something still go wrong set permissions like :

1. chmod 777 dir/*
2. chmod 777 dir/file.html

Comment: This ended up working. Thank you much. (I had to restart apache as well)

Comment: Nice to hear, i use this config but i have some little problem here, if my app lives not inside a django_project folder,  templates not loading. For example we have /folder/ contains  myapp,  django_project.